# Hide TD into DIV Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide TD into DIV Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114138/hide-td-into-div-using-jquery)

I'm Trying to Hide an div with all TD But Only hide the text into the div and no hide the TD tags somebody know how to fix this? My Code is:

jQuery Code:

```
$('div#default_results').hide();
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='default_results'>
Div Content
<td class='rand_code'>
TD Content
</td>
</div>
```

The Result:

```
<td class='rand_code'>
TD Content
</td>
```