# Hide TD into DIV Using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm Trying to Hide an div with all TD But Only hide the text into the div and no hide the TD tags somebody know how to fix this? My Code is:

jQuery Code:

```
$('div#default_results').hide();
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='default_results'>
Div Content
<td class='rand_code'>
TD Content
</td>
</div>
```

The Result:

```
<td class='rand_code'>
TD Content
</td>
```

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding this question. Do you think you could more clearly describe what you're trying to do and what's wrong with the current result?

Comment: <td>'s live in <tr>'s which live in <table>'s - did yours run away or something? Why are you not just using an inner <div>?

Comment: I have multiple TDs into a div and i need to hide all these tds using jQuery

Comment: Is it even valid to have a div inside a table body, but outside the td?  Why wouldn't you be hiding the entire row tr.

Comment: @blackriderws - you don't have what you think you have. In the DOM, your `div` does not wrap the `td`s at all, so you have no chance of hiding the `td`s by hiding the `div`. See DaveRandom's comment for why.

Comment: It's not valid.  I once tried that in order try to hide entire rows at once before I discovered that you can have multiple tbody tags and hide those instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide TD into DIV Using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099777/hide-td-into-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid mark-up.  You can not have divs or text between td's.  You will have to restructure your page to achieve whatever the goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$('.rand_code').hide();`
or
`$("#default_results td").hide();`

Comment: The code Works but i have multiples TD into the div and i want to hide each element

Comment: He wants to hide the text in the div but skip over the the table td i guess. Looks like his markup is incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you said:

```
$("#default_results").replaceWith($("#default_results").find("td"));
```

Comment: No Mate dont works i tried this code too and dont hide nothing :S

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a cross-browser issue I have run into before - some browsers [IE] will apply the opacity css property (which is how `hide()` works) to the object it is called on and all it's content, and some [FF] will apply it to the container only and the content will still be visible.

The only solution I ever managed to find that worked everywhere was to call `hide()` on both the container and all the elements it contains. This is overkill in browsers that have already hidden it but it does work.

I have not tested this for some time so my statements about which browsers will/will not support this may no longer be true.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid markup and it should work:

```
<div>
  Div Content
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Table Content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```